# Any Way to Streamline this Logic?

Tags: entity-framework

I've written some code that translates an Entity Framework collection to some fixed fields. I ended up with the following snippet but isn't there a slicker way to accomplish this?

```
var numbers = c.ContactPhoneNumbers.OrderByDescending(n => n.IsPrimary);

int count = 0;
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        hc.PrimaryPhone = number.PhoneNumber;
        hc.PrimaryPhoneType = number.PhoneNumberType;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        hc.SecondaryPhone = number.PhoneNumber;
        hc.SecondaryPhoneType = number.PhoneNumberType;
    }
    else break;
    count++;
}
```

`c` is an Entity Framework entity and `c.ContactPhoneNumbers` represents entries in a related table. Seems like this code could be made a little more straight forward and less awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are iterating the phone enumeration right away, might be better to use `ToList()` so you can use the indexer:

```
var numbers = c.ContactPhoneNumbers.OrderByDescending(n => n.IsPrimary).ToList();
if(numbers.Count > 0)
{
  hc.PrimaryPhone = numbers[0].PhoneNumber;
  hc.PrimaryPhoneType = number[0].PhoneNumberType;
}
if(numbers.Count > 1)
{
  hc.SecondaryPhone = numbers[1].PhoneNumber;
  hc.SecondaryPhoneType = numbers[1].PhoneNumberType;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that might be my best route.